# Window function to find differences in String

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a table like the below in MS SQL Server with the first two columns, I would like to apply some kind of window function partitioned by fund_name to output the differences in security_name to give the desired_output?

Is there such a way? I could maybe try reading the data into python but can't think of solution using either.

There will be no consistency in the pattern of desired_output.

| Fund_Name | Security_Name | Desired_Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Morgan Stanley Investment Sust Asn Eq Fd | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Sustainable Asian Equity Fund Z | Z |
| Morgan Stanley Investment Sust Asn Eq Fd | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Sustainable Asian Equity Fund B | B |
| Morgan Stanley Investment Sust Asn Eq Fd | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Sustainable Asian Equity Fund I | I |
| Morgan Stanley Investment Sust Asn Eq Fd | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Sustainable Asian Equity Fund A | A |
| MS INVF Emerging Markets Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Emerging Markets Equity Fund Z | Z |
| MS INVF Emerging Markets Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Emerging Markets Equity Fund I | I |
| MS INVF Latin American Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Latin American Equity Fund A | A |
| MS INVF Latin American Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Latin American Equity Fund I | I |
| MS INVF Latin American Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Latin American Equity Fund B | B |
| MS INVF Latin American Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Latin American Equity Fund C | C |
| MS INVF Latin American Equity Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - Latin American Equity Fund Z | Z |
| MS INVF US Growth Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - US Growth Fund A | A |
| MS INVF US Growth Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - US Growth Fund AH (EUR) | AH (EUR) |
| MS INVF US Growth Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - US Growth Fund NH (EUR) | NH (EUR) |
| MS INVF US Growth Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - US Growth Fund BH (EUR) | BH (EUR) |
| MS INVF US Growth Fund | Morgan Stanley Investment Funds - US Growth Fund Z | Z |

Comment: Define `differences`. The desired output isn't the difference between two strings. It's the non-common part of the "current" string. You'll have to find the common part between the "current" string and some other. `FIRST_VALUE` or `LAST_VALUE` could give you that other string. That's hard enough already. Trying to find the common substring between all the elements in a partition is far harder. SQL, especially T-SQL, is *not* good at string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

using the pattern provided, you can measure if the length of the last term is equal to 1, then append it, else check if it's in brackets (), then append the slice of the last 2 string splits, else apply some additional logic you have, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

mydata=pd.read_csv("so.csv")
out=[]
for security in mydata['Security_Name']:
    if len(security.split()[-1])==1:
        out.append(security.split()[-1])
    elif security[-1]==")":
        out.append(security.split()[-2:])
    else:
        out.append("add new logic here")
mydata["new_logic"]=pd.DataFrame(out)
print(mydata)
```